# Eliminate all parameters from the differential equation $u_t-Au_x-Bu^3+Cu_{xx}=0$.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

> The question is to scale the equation $$u_t-Au_x-Bu^3+Cu_{xx}=0$$ to eliminate all parameters.
>
> where $D>0$ and $A,B$ are nonzero.

I tried to substitute $U=U(x/L,t/t_0)$ into the equation and tried to find the appropriate value of $L,t_0$. I get $U_{\tau}t_0^{-1}=AU_{\xi}L^{-1}-bU^3+DL^{-2}U_{\xi\xi}$.

Then I tried but don't know how find the appropriate $t_0$ and $L$ to eliminate all parameters.
Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: Multiply both sides by $t_0$ and then set each parameter "aggregate" (e.g. $AL^{-1}t_0$) equal to $1$. Then solve for $L,t_0$. But unless $u$ itself has dimensions, this will not work: eliminating two dimensioned quantities will only eliminate two of your three parameters. If $u$ itself has dimensions independent of the dimensions of $x$ and $t$ (e.g. if $u$ is a temperature), then you should introduce $u/u_0$ as well.

Comment: Being a bit more explicit, consider $u(x,t)/u_0=U(x/x_0,t/t_0)$. Then $u_t=u_0 t_0^{-1} U_\tau$, $u_x=u_0 x_0^{-1} U_\xi$, etc.

Comment: You need three scaling parameters, it cannot be done with only two, because you are seeking to eliminate three independent parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale: $u = \frac{A}{\sqrt{BC}} U$, $t = \frac{C}{A^2} \tau, x = \frac{C}{A} \xi$.

To find this notice that you can adjust the scales of $u, t, x$, make such general scaling and solve for the conditions needed to factor the same prefactor out of all the equation. With the substitution above this prefactor should be

$$
\frac{A^3}{C\sqrt{BC}} = \Lambda
$$
Notice that you will also need $B>0$ to this end.
Your equation becomes:

$$
\Lambda (U_{\tau} - U_{\xi} - U^3 + U_{\xi \xi}) = 0
$$
dividing by $\Lambda$ also requires $A \neq 0$, and gives the equation you are looking for.